# Copy entire row under current column, based on value in cell

Tags: vba, excel, copy, row

[code that covers my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524408/excel-vba-macro-copy-rows-multiple-times-based-on-a-cell-integer-value?rq=1)

I'm trying to copy entire row under current column, based on value in cell.
When in A1 is 5, then copy it 5 times.
The code that i found is limited to few columns in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code recreates the table in a new sheet.

To update the code you could replace

```
Sheet2.Range("A" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A" & currentRow).Value2
Sheet2.Range("B" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2
Sheet2.Range("C" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Sheet1.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2
```

with

```
    Sheet2.Range("A" & currentNewSheetRow).entirerow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A" & currentRow).entirerow.Value2
```

Which will copy the values for the entire row.