# If column contains number greater than 1, replicate that row that many times

Tags: vba, excel, insert, row

Ok, so I got that working, and added my code to change another column in the same loop, my final challenge is to look at my Q column, which contains the quantity of the items ordered, and IF it is > 1 THEN copy the entire row, and paste it into newly inserted rows for however many over 1 the quantity was. 
Example

```
Josh   Smith  Soda    1
John   Doe    Banana  3
Tony   Brown  Cake    1
```

Would need to become

```
Josh   Smith  Soda    1
John   Doe    Banana  3
John   Doe    Banana  3
John   Doe    Banana  3
Tony   Brown  Cake    1
```

My code thus far is:

```
Sub prepLabels()
Dim i As Long
For i = 3 To Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row Step 1
    If Cells(i, "Q") > 1 Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

But obviously I failed at something, as my first row simply replicates 7 times or something.

Comment: Check this post on SO, its similar to what you are looking for and hope you find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524408/excel-vba-macro-copy-rows-multiple-times-based-on-a-cell-integer-value

Answer (score 1):

When inserting rows, always start at the bottom and work towards the top so that the inserted rows do not conflict with your iteration count.

```
Sub prepLabels()
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, lr As Long
    With ActiveSheet   'define this worksheet properly!
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lr To 3 Step -1
            For r = 2 To .Cells(i, "Q").Value2
                .Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(i, 1).Resize(2, Columns.Count).FillDown
            Next r
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You know, I don't know why I didn't think to work from the bottom....That worked perfectly, not to get the rest of my code in with it and I'll be done for the weekend. Cheers!