# Merging 2 worksheets and copy all rows of worksheet 1 multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

Thanks in advance.
If there's anyone out there with the knowledge to this all, I would be very delighted ;-) And that doesn't have to be in VBA, a sollution in excel-formulas is welcome also if possible.

I'm trying to do the following:
There is a worksheet with 6000+ companynames. Another worksheet shows it's types of tasks that can be signed to every single company.
I want to create a new worksheet with n-times every companyname and after it's last column on every row one of the tasks.

**Worksheet1:**

CompanyA|AdressA|CityA

CompanyB|AdressB|CityB

**Worksheet2:**

Task1|Explanation1|Duration1

Task2|Explanation2|Duration2

**New Worksheet3 to create:**

CompanyA|AdressA|CityA|Task1|Explanation1|Duration1

CompanyA|AdressA|CityA|Task2|Explanation2|Duration2

CompanyB|AdressB|CityB|Task1|Explanation1|Duration1

CompanyB|AdressB|CityB|Task2|Explanation2|Duration2

My way of **starting** is copying the rows of worksheet1 n-times and I found an older thread that could be usefull.
[This is where I found something about copying 1 row multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524408/excel-vba-macro-copy-rows-multiple-times-based-on-a-cell-integer-value)

I custommade it a little (my excel version is Dutch, so "sheet" is "blad"). Unfortunatly this doesn't work and gives an error.

```
    Sub DuplicateRows()

Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim currentNewSheetRow As Integer: currentNewSheetRow = 1

For currentRow = 1 To 5 'The last row of your data

    Dim timesToDuplicate As Integer
    timesToDuplicate = CInt(Blad1.Range("O" & currentRow).Value2) ' Error line

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To timesToDuplicate

        Blad3.Range("A" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Blad1.Range("A" & currentRow).Value2
        Blad3.Range("B" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Blad1.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2
        Blad3.Range("C" & currentNewSheetRow).Value2 = Blad1.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2

        currentNewSheetRow = currentNewSheetRow + 1

    Next i

Next currentRow

End Sub
```

The error appears on this line (error 13 Type mismatch):

`timesToDuplicate = CInt(Blad1.Range("O" & currentRow).Value2)`

Comment: You are asking for a cartesian product, which is something you can do with Power Query. Google for **excel power query cartesian product** and you will find plenty of guides

Comment: @Could you please upload images for both sheets?

Comment: I posted the images. Made it simple to keep real data private ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Error1004: Here are the images for the sheets.

[image]
[image]
[image]